# Can't update node value in a childAutoId node to update dictionary values

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on weight tracking app when i am adding new data to firebase it is work properly but when i am updating the data from that date the new data is adding with existing emails unique id i want to update current dates weight if i add weight again on that date 
[the black round showing where i want to update the weight and remaining other data is where actual data is updating

here is my code too.

```
@IBAction func addButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let time = Date()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
    let formatteddate = formatter.string(from: time as Date)
    if formatteddate == addDate.text!{
        self.UpdateTaskWithName(name: addWeight.text!, date: addDate.text!) { (success) in
            print("**** TASK UPDATED *******")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

                }
            }

    }else{

        if let text = self.addWeight.text{
            if let date = self.addDate.text{

                self.saveTaskWithName(name: text, date: date, completionHandler: { (success) in
                    print("****  NEW TASK ADDED *******")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
                    }
                })
            }
        }

    }

}

func saveTaskWithName(name:String,date:String, completionHandler:@escaping ((_ success:Bool)->Void)){
    let dict = ["weight": name, "date" : date] as [String : Any]
    if let userid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid{
        self.ref.child("WeightTracker").child(userid).childByAutoId().setValue(dict) { (error, reference) in

            if let err = error{
                print(err.localizedDescription)
            }else{
                // data save successfully
                completionHandler(true)
            }
        }
    }
}



func UpdateTaskWithName(name:String,date:String, completionHandler:@escaping ((_ success:Bool)->Void)){
    let dict = ["weight": name, "date" : date] as [String : Any]
    if let userid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid{
        self.ref.child("WeightTracker").child(userid).updateChildValues(dict) { (error, reference) in

            if let err = error{
                print(err.localizedDescription)
            }else{
                // data save successfully
                completionHandler(true)

             }
         }
     }
 }
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Why don't you use just one level child with auto id after WeightTracker? What I see is that you are adding data to `WeightTracker > child(id) > childAutoId > data`. But when you want to update data you are doing `WeightTracker > child(id) > data`.

In case you want to maintain your structure you have to access `WeightTracker > child(id) > childAutoId > data` if you would like to override the values of those two keys (`date` and `weight`).

Comment: can you show me ? i will be very thankful .

Comment: What would you like to achieve when you do ADD NEW TASK and UPDATE TASK? What do you expect your structure to look like in firebase?

Comment: when i add new task if date is new then new data will be added and if i add new data to existing date  data will be updated.

Comment: like in image if my date is "19.05.2019" . and then i enter weight to the that date agin  only weight would be updated .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this example you can do a `query` to find the `node` where your date matches the one you are interested to update if found. That query will return you the `key` to the node (for the `childByAutoId` node) that you can use to update the child `weight`:

```
func UpdateTaskWithName(name:String, date:String, completionHandler:@escaping ((_ success:Bool)->Void)){
    if let userid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
        self.ref.child("WeightTracker")
            .child(userid)
            .queryOrdered(byChild: "date")
            .queryEqual(toValue: date)
            .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                self.ref.child("WeightTracker").child(userid).child(snapshot.key).child("weight").setValue(name)
            })
     }
 }
```

This would be how your function would look like taking in consideration that with `name` you mean your `date` coming from the UI TextField and considering.

The function could be also made more meaningful to read by splitting some of the actions into variable instances and re-using them like this:

```
func UpdateTaskWithName(name:String, date:String, completionHandler:@escaping ((_ success:Bool)->Void)){
    if let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
        let userIDRef = self.ref.child("WeightTracker").child(userID)
        let query = userIDRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "date").queryEqual(toValue: date)
        query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                let childByAutoIDNodeKey = snapshot.key
                let refToUpdate = userIDRef.child(childByAutoIDNodeKey).child("weight")
                refToUpdate.setValue(name)
                completionHandler(true)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: its showing this error  "Unable to infer closure type in the current context" in 7th line of function.

Comment: i tried its showing "Argument labels '(of:, with:)' do not match any available overloads"  this error sir

Comment: @ronakjani Sorry I was not really available before. I just took time and updated my original answer due to the typo that made "Argument labels " error go away. Can you retry?

Answer (score 0):

To find a solution, let's first identify the issue.

Here's your structure

```
Weighttracker
    user_uid_0
       child_by_auto_id_0
          date: "19.05.2019"
          weight: "236"
```

assuming you want to update the weight for that date, here's your update code

```
self.ref.child("WeightTracker").child(userid).updateChildValues(dict)
```

Remember that when using updateChildValues, if they don't exist, they will be added. Here's the path you're code updating those child values at

```
WeightTracker/uid/values being updated here
```

when what you want is

```
WeighTtracker/uid/childByAutoId/values being updated here
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The problem is that you don't know what childByAutoId is so you cannot directly update that data.

There are a couple of of solutions; one being to use the date as the key to the node, which would mean your structure would need to be changed

```
WeightTracker
    user_uid_0
       20190519
          weight: "236"
```

Then the update becomes simple

```
let userid = Auth.auth().currentUser.uid
let pathRef = self.ref.child(WeightTracker).child(userid).child(date)
pathRef.child("weight").setValue(weight)
```

Another option using your existing structure is to query for the node where date equals the date you want, then get the key to that node, then do the update to the child weight node

```
func updateViaQuery() {
    let uid = //users uid
    let uidRef = self.ref.child("WeightTracker").child(uid)
    let query = uidRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "date").queryEqual(toValue: "19.05.2019")
    query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let key = snapshot.key
        let refToUpdate = uidRef.child(key).child("weight")
        refToUpdate.setValue(weight)
    })
}
```

The only issue with the second method is that the query would return no results if the date doesn't exist so you would want to ensure it does before doing an update.